# Bash: Filter rows by line number

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

If I have a delimited file with many lines and columns (`data.txt`):

```
346 dfd asw  34
565 sd  wdew 34
667 ffg wew  23
473 sa  as   21
533 jhf qwe  54
```

and another file with line numbers that I want to extract (`positions.txt`)

```
3
5
8
```

How do I use the `positions.txt` file to extract those positions from `data.txt`? This is the result I would expect for this example:

```
667 ffg wew  23
533 jhf qwe  54
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply with **`awk`**:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ pos[$1]; next }FNR in pos' positions.txt data.txt
```

- `NR==FNR{ ... }` - processing the 1st input file (i.e. `positions.txt`):

  - `pos[$1]` - accumulating positions(record numbers) set as `pos` array keys
  - `next` - jump to next record
- `FNR in pos` - while processing the 2nd input file `data.txt`(`FNR` indicates how many records have been read from the current input file). Print record only if current record number `FNR` is in array of positions `pos` (search on keys)

---

Sample output:

```
667 ffg wew  23
533 jhf qwe  54
...
```

Comment: This seems to be much faster than the `sed` version below.

Answer (score 5):

First create a `sed` script from the `positions.txt` file:

```
sed 's/$/p/' positions.txt
```

This will output

```
3p
5p
8p
```

This simple script will just print the indicated lines.

Then apply this to the `data.txt` file. If you're using `bash` (or any shell that understands process substitutions with `<( ... )`):

```
sed -n -f <( sed 's/$/p/' positions.txt ) data.txt
```

The `-n` stops `sed` from outputting anything other than what's explicitly printed by the given `sed` script.

With the examples given, this will yield

```
667 ffg wew  23
533 jhf qwe  54
```

---

If not using `bash`, then

```
sed 's/$/p/' positions.txt >filter.sed
sed -n -f filter.sed data.txt
rm -f filter.sed
```

... will do the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

If `positions.txt` is sorted, it's also possible to do this in a single pass through both files, and without storing `positions.txt` in full. Simply read the next line off `positions.txt` when the previous matching line is met:

```
$ awk -vpos=positions.txt 'function get() { getline num < pos } 
     BEGIN { get() } NR==num { print; get() }' data.txt                 
667 ffg wew  23
533 jhf qwe  54
```

In practice, this is only useful if both files are really huge or you're really, *really* low on memory.

Answer (score 1):

```
join <(cat -n data.txt) positions.txt | cut -d ' ' -f2-
```

Comment: Won't work for files with more than ten lines

Answer (score 0):

we can do this by simple for loop

Method1 using sed and for loop

```
for i in `cat positions.txt`; do sed -n ""$i"p" data.txt ; done
```

output

```
667 ffg wew  23
533 jhf qwe  54
```

Method2 using awk and for loop

```
for i in `cat positions.txt`; do awk -v i="$i" 'NR==i {print $0}' data.txt ;done
```

output

```
667 ffg wew  23
533 jhf qwe  54
```

Comment: These do have the downside that you'll read all of  `data.txt` as many times as there are lines to pick out, which may be an issue if the file is very large. Then again, if the list of lines to pick is very large, that could also be an issue. Also, you do know that `""$i"p"` leaves the `$i` unquoted, and that the `""` at the start is a no-op? That might be better written as `"${i}p"`.